# Password On Contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am sharing personal contacts information with another employee, we are using Outlook 2013 on a exchange server. My question "Is there a way for me to put a password on his contacts information on my system?" So if someone tried to view his contacts on my system, they would automatically be asked to enter in a password to view his contacts information.

Comment: A bit confused on this one...  You're OK with someone being able to read all your emails, access your files, send emails on your behalf, etc--but your concern is the privacy of your co-worker's contacts?  If they are signed onto exchange as you, then they are you, as far as the computer is concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Beside the point of my information. Is there a way for me put a password on his contacts information in my outlook? Since he shares his contacts with me.

Comment: Nope.  His contacts are now your contacts.  Put a password on the computer instead.

Comment: The point was that it is password protected, with your outlook credentials.  No, there does not appear to be a way to add a second layer to this.  Permissions in outlook are based on authentication, not on fixed passwords.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help Madball73 and techie007